# React Router createBrowserRouter vs Browser Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am starting a new React project and want to use the latest version of React Router. The docs recommend using createBrowserRouter for all web projects. They don't say why it is better than using BrowserRouter other than it enables some data APIs.

What is the main difference between these two?

Comment: They make that recommendation because createBrowserRouter supports data APIs and BrowserRouter does not. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router#picking-a-router

Comment: "They don't say why it is better than using BrowserRouter other than it enables some data APIs" - The documentation ***doesn't*** say one is better than the other. OFC they they will obviously likely suggest/recommend the nice new shiny thing. If you don't need route loaders/actions, then there is not much to gain by using the Data APIs.

Answer (score 0):

`createBrowserRouter()` offers several capabilities that `<BrowserRouter>` does not.

The first is the ability to leverage [Data APIs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router#data-apis) that provide consistent patterns for loading data, validating data, and making that data available to the components rendered in your routes.

Additionally with `createBrowserRouter()` you can define your route configuration as "data" (array of JavaScript objects) rather than as JSX tags, providing a higher level of flexibility in configuring your routes.

As React Router itself is promoting the use of `createBrowserRouter()`, and the fact that it is functionally compatible with `<BrowserRouter>`, I would personally take that as a signal of the future direction of the codebase.  This could be a hint to some future deprecations....but that is purely an guess-from-experience on my part.